# String Returns True/False

Tags: javascript, html, string

So I'm trying to mimic my code with the instructions given but I'm not sure as to how one returns these specified string examples, I've done as much as I could but I'm stuck as to what to do next, how does one approach it?

I've added true and false statements but I'm not sure as to how to get JS to act the way it needs to be or where to begin it.

[image: Instructions]

My HTML:

```
<!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Strings True/False</title>
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="strings.js"></script>
<style>
  body {
  margin-left: 15%;
  font-family: monospace;
  }
  .r { color: blue};
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> String Test </h1>
    <p> Example 1 </p>
    <p> <input id="input1" type="text"> </p>
    <p id="regex1"> Regular Expression : [**Replace with regex**] </p>
    <p id="result1" class="r"> Result: </p>
    <p> <button id="b1"> Press to evaluate your string </button> </p>
    <hr>
    <p> Example 2 </p>
    <p> <input id="input2" type="text"> </p>
    <p id="regex2"> Regular Expression : [**Replace with regex**] </p>
    <p id="result2" class="r"> Result: </p>
    <p> <button id="b2"> Press to evaluate your string </button> </p>
    <hr>
    <p> Example 3 </p>
    <p> <input id="input3" type="text"> </p>
    <p id="regex3"> Regular Expression : [**Replace with regex**]</p>
    <p id="result3" class="r"> Result: </p>
    <p> <button id="b3"> Press to evaluate your string </button> </p>
    <hr>
    <p> Example 4 </p>
    <p> <input id="input4" type="text"> </p>
    <p id="regex4"> Regular Expression :[**Replace with regex**] </p>
    <p id="result4" class="r"> Result: </p>
    <p> <button id="b4"> Press to evaluate your string </button> </p>
    <hr>
    <p> Example 5 </p>
    <p> <input id="input5" type="text"> </p>
    <p id="regex5"> Regular Expression : [**Replace with regex**] </p>
    <p id="result5" class="r"> Result: </p>
    <p> <button id="b5"> Press to evaluate your string </button> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
    window.onload = function() {
      $("b1").observe("click", myFunction1);
      $("b2").observe("click", myFunction2);
      $("b3").observe("click", myFunction3);
      $("b4").observe("click", myFunction4);
      $("b5").observe("click", myFunction5);
    }

    function myFunction1() {
      // Function re for a number that begins from 0-9 and any number after
      var re = /^[0-9]+/;
      var testString = $("input1").value;

      if (re.test(testString) == true)
      {
        $("result1").innerHTML = "Result: TRUE";
      }
      else {
        $("result1").innerHTML = "Result: FALSE";
      }
    }


    function myFunction2() {

      var re;
      var testString = $("input2").value;

      if (re.test(testString) == true)
      {
        $("result2").innerHTML = "Result: TRUE";
      }
      else {
        $("result2").innerHTML = "Result: FALSE";
      }
    }


    function myFunction3() {

      var re;
      var testString = $("input3").value;

      if (re.test(testString) == true)
      {
        $("result3").innerHTML = "Result: TRUE";
      }
      else {
        $("result3").innerHTML = "Result: FALSE";
      }
    }

    function myFunction4() {

      var re;
      var testString = $("input4").value;

      if (re.test(testString) == true)
      {
        $("result4").innerHTML = "Result: TRUE";
      }
      else {
        $("result4").innerHTML = "Result: FALSE";
      }
    }

    function myFunction5() {

      var re;
      var testString = $("input5").value;

      if (re.test(testString) == true)
      {
        $("result5").innerHTML = "Result: TRUE";
      }
      else {
        $("result5").innerHTML = "Result: FALSE";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what a regular expression is? If so, what have you tried? If not, please read about them, and then try.

Comment: so I tried creating a regular expression for the first one that begins with a number and any number afterwards, am I doing it right? @trincot

Comment: It's a good start, but it does not take care yet of *"...and any number after"*.

Comment: Here's an incredibly handy tool for creating and testing regex: https://regex101.com/ . Another top tip is to name you functions more descriptively than `function1`.

Comment: @trincot what about now? I added in the + so that way it displays any number afterwards unlimited times, im just not sure as to how to generate it so it evaluates the string function

Comment: Did you try to run it, enter text and click the button? Anyway, this is not really the place to review, correct, review, correct, ...etc. Have a go at it and when you bump into a specific problem, dedicate a question on that.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you're building an exercise page to test user's knowledge of regular expressions. In that case, when you're doing this:

```
  var re;
  var testString = $("input1").value;

  if (re.test(testString) == true)
```

, you're actually doing the opposite of what you're trying to achieve. `re` is supposed to be the RegExp itself and `testString` is a string you're testing against the said RegExp. What you need to do is

1) create RegExp object from a string in a user input, with the use of [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_regular_expression), i.e. something like `var re = new RegExp($("input1").value)`

2) having a set of your pre-made test strings ('examples' in your screenshot), test them against the RegExp they typed in

3) output the result in the html

Comment: so I tried creating a variable re that starts off with a number and can do any number afterwards, am I doing it correct?